# Probability of picking certain things from a set

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 15 fruits in a set. We know 10 are apples and the other 5 are oranges. What is the probability that most of the fruits selected are apples? (Express as answer as a quotient of two natural numbers).

Comment: In any sample?  Or some specific size?

Comment: I am told *most* of the fruits selected. The answers happens to be $\frac{834}{1001}$. That is as much as I know for this problem.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without details of the selection process.

Comment: Please don't phrase posts as if you were assigning us homework; it's especially grating when you "order" people how to give you their answers.

Comment: You need to know *how many* fruit you are selecting. If you are selecting one fruit, then the odds are $\frac{2}{3}$; if you are selecting $11$ fruit, then the odds are $1$. The problem is nonsensical as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answers happens to be $\frac{834}{1001}$.

Then the missing part of your question is that five fruits are selected at random.

Comment: I wish I could add the 'reverse-mathematics' tag to this answer. :-)